# R-finding unmatched column names of data frames

Tags: r

I have two large data frames(df1 and df2). I want to combine them using rbind function:

```
df<-rbind(df1,df2)
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
names do not match previous names
```

There more than 100 variables in the data frames. I know most names match. One or two names may not match. How can I find unmatched column names of df1 and df2. I will be very glad for any help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `colnames` will give you the column names of a `data.frame`. If they don't match, you can set the column names of one of them and then `rbind` them. For instance `colnames(df2)<-colnames(df1);df<-rbind(df1,df2)`. What's the purpose of the `fill` argument?

Comment: "fill" argument fills missing columns with NA nicola

Comment: Well... no. I don't know where you got that info, but there isn't any `fill` argument in `rbind`. I have the last R version (3.1.2).

Comment: Ok, nicola, I edited the question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use `setdiff`:

```
a <- c("a", "b", "c")
b <- c("b", "c", "d")
setdiff(a, b)
#[1] "a"
setdiff(b, a)
#[1] "d"
```

where `a` is, e.g., `names(df1)`.